# WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, visio, windowsformshost

I'm having some troubles using context menu on Visio Drawing Control hosted in a WPF application. The DrawingControl is hosted by a WindowsFormsHost control, and I want to override the standard right click behaviour adding a custom ContextMenu like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="_WFHost"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <visio:AxDrawingControl x:Name="_drawingControl"/> 

        <WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu StaysOpen="True" Name="VisioContextMenu">
                <MenuItem x:Name="QuotaMenuItem" Header="Quota" Click="QuotaMenuItem_Click"/>

                <MenuItem x:Name="TraslaMenuItem" Header="Trasla" Click="TraslaMenuItem_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

In the codebehind file I manange the mouseUp event of the DrawingControl in order to obtain that my context menu shows up instead of the Visio standard one.
The ContextMenu (in the code named as VisioContextMenu) shows up but after about 2 seconds it disappears both if I don't do anything or I interact with it.

When I want to show the ContextMenu I always set IsOpen and StaysOpen properties to true, but it behaves as stated before. I really don't know what to do!

Do you have some hints?
Thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted your code as well, but I would say make sure that you are correctly handling the mouseup event.

That alone could be the problem - try removing that event.